# Save state in segmented control in Swift

Tags: swift

In my swift app, i have segmented control with 3 tabs. In 1st tab, graph will be drawn when user presses custom ui button.

Now problem is, when user tap 2nd or 3rd tab and come back to 1st tab, it is reset to default. (i.e Graph is not visible. But if user press custom ui button again, then graph is drawn)

But i don't want to redraw graph every time when user comes to 1st tab. How to save/maintain the state of 1st tab?

Comment: Do you mean TabViewController instead of a segmented control?

Comment: No. In segmented control only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have change the visibility of graph view to hidden on selected on that index. you should make the visibility to always true of that view when selected on that index.

@IBAction func segmentControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

```
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
       self.drawGraph.hidden = false //or do nothing for this view
    case 1:
        self.drawGraph.hidden = true
    case 2:
        self.drawGraph.hidden = true
    default:
        break; 
    }
}
```